# Can degrees be "established"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I wanted to convey that a university degree is true and valid, but I am not sure if the word "established" can be used for the degree itself.

1. Any suggestions on which words I can use to convey that same meaning for a "degree"?
2. Can I check if it is the word "established" can be used for an educational program?

Comment: Degrees are *awarded* or *conferred*. A degree may also be termed a *credential*, but that is a broader term.

Comment: @Robusto: I believe this is about confirming reputation, value and validity of a degree (vs junk diplomas from fake schools).

Comment: Yes SF! That is what I'm trying to say!

Comment: Is it lack of trust of the degree itself, or lack of trust about the institution? 'Accredited' is what is used for a university or program. For the degree itself, that's sort of a strange thing to doubt the degree.

Comment: @Mitch Well, actually I am doing a comparison between online degrees and classroom-style traditional degrees

Comment: @Karen: see how other people write about it. 'on-line degree' for those that are, but I guess you're looking for a simple way to express the traditional one? Like 'brick-and-mortar' store? 'On-line' degrees can come from accredited programs though.

Comment: @Karen: In this case "established" is a valid word, to denote world-recognized degrees as opposed to made-up ones (say, "proffessor[sic]") but it still doesn't say a thing about their reputation. I know "University of Phoenix" was known to provide "online university courses" which required paying some big $$$, then finding an answer sheet and filling a test according to it, to pass a semester, and then you'd get a completely valid, fully accredited and totally worthless established degree - while you'd have right to call yourself BoA, employer seeing BoA diploma from UoPh. would laugh at you.

Comment: I would tend to read "established" as referring to the actions that resulted in that university beginning to confer that degree to students, vs referring to the conferring of the degree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think claiming a PhD is an established degree will convey any valuable information to the reader.

I believe the words you're looking for are *recognized, reputable, prestigious*. You may also pick nouns that are directly related to degrees: *Graduates, diplomas*.

Comment: @Karen if you like this answer, please vote it up, and consider clicking the checkmark icon to accept it.

Comment: @Karen Thank you and welcome to english.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You can *establish* the *validity* or *legitimacy* of a degree. You can also state that a degree is *authentic*, *legitimate*, *genuine* or *bonafide*. You can also use similar adjectives to describe the institution which conferred the degree.

You can find related synonyms in a [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/bona+fide?s=ts).

Answer (score 0):

I like a word you suggested, *true*.

> She received a true degree in 1999.

Although I don't know if that is making a strong statement than the simpler:

> She received a degree in 1999.

If you represent the university, then perhaps

> We confirm (authenticate) that she received a degree in 1999.

As to the second part of your question, *establish* is a fine word to use, as in

> UNC established the Mathematical Finance graduate degree in 2002.

You might also say,

> UNC first conferred the Mathematical Finance graduate degree in 2004.

If the emphasis is on what a third-party has established about the program, then you might say,

> The M.A. in Counseling was accredited in 2006.

If these answers don't suffice, then perhaps the beta site, academics.stackexchange.com, might be of help.